# Capturing Dataframe element as part of CSV file name

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file with multiple rows. I read it as a dataframe. Then I am looking up the row values of the dataframe in another file and doing filtering to extract matching row values and write it as a separate csv file for each  matching value.

The first CSV file I read:

[image]

The second csv file I look into is:

[image]

As there are 5 matching values the output should give me 5 csv for each matching value.
So I expect an csv output for example for value 333 like below:

[image]

This is the code I have done so far but not getting expected output. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv('LookupPCI.csv')
df2=pd.read_csv('All_PCI.csv')

for i,r in df1.iterrows():
    df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['PHYCELLID'], right_index=False)
    df3.to_csv("Looked up PCI list"+df1['PHYCELLID']+".csv",index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to store your DataFrames in new variables, just write them to csv after filtering:

```
for pid in df1["PHYCELLID"]:
    df2[df2["PHYCELLID"].eq(pid)].to_csv(f"Looked up PCI list {pid}.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

You were merging the entire DataFrame df1, rather than just the row that you were iterating.

Same thing was happening while exporting to csv file.

I've parsed the int values for 'PHYCELLID' column to str, while exporting to csv (for the file naming convention) as well.

Hope this helps!

```py
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv('LookupPCI.csv')
df2=pd.read_csv('All_PCI.csv')

for i,r in df1.iterrows():
    df3 = pd.merge(r, df2, on=['PHYCELLID'], right_index=False)
    df3.to_csv("Looked up PCI list "+str(r['PHYCELLID'])+".csv",index=False)
```